# Winforms accessing connectionstrings in multiple projects

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, multiple-projects

I have for example 3 Winforms projects inside the same solution.

- Project1
- Project2
- Project3

When I build the solution, all the projects and his respectives files (.exe) are generated.
The problem is: Each project uses different connectionstring and just the solutions .config file is generated in the Bin folder.
When I deploy the solution to my customer, the project1 and project2 (for example) shows errors regarding to connectionstring problems (diferent Data Source, UserId and Password).

I've tried to put the connectionstring inside the .config file generated but it's not working too.

How can I manage these connectionstrings and works well when I deploy my programs ?

Regards

Jr

Answer (score 0):

Each project needs to have its own connection string if it won't be connecting the same database/schema/or has same permissions on the DB. So you will have to change the name of the connection string for each project and place each of those connection strings in the config file of the built exe.

Then each project will be able to access its own connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Add app.config to each project. You can store the connection strings specific to your project/assembly in this file. Then should be no problems.